# Append column values from a 2d array to the rows of another 2d array based on shared column values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Let's say I have following arrays:

```
$first = [
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Education'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Computers'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Science'],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Sports'],
];

$second = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Sport'],
    ['id' => 7, 'title' => 'Sci'],
    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'Comp'],
    ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'Edu'],
];
```

And desired output is:

```
[
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Education', 'title' => 'Edu'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Computers', 'title' => 'Comp'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Science', 'title' => 'Sci'],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Sports', 'title' => 'Sport'],
]
```

I have managed to merge these arrays with simply:

```
foreach ($first as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = array_merge($first[$key], $second[$key]);
}
```

But the output is combined by first level index instead of their `id` value:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [name] => Education
                [title] => Sport
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => Computers
                [title] => Sci
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [name] => Science
                [title] => Comp

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Sports
                [title] => Edu
            )
    )
```

I would like to append the title values from the second array to the first array where there is a matching `id` value and maintain the sorting of the first array.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related page where rows are indexed instead of associative and the two arrays do not have the same length/ids: [Merge two indexed arrays of indexed arrays based on first column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8879767/2943403)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just do a nested loop and check if the `id` values match, then add `title` to `$first` (or `name` to `$second`)

```
foreach($first as $key => $value){
    foreach($second as $value2){
        if($value['id'] === $value2['id']){
            $first[$key]['title'] = $value2['title'];
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of this? O(n^2)? It can be definitely done better.

Comment: The time complexity won't be awesome because there is no conditional break in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

You code works fine. Your expectations are simply incorrect. For example in one array 4th element `id` holds 1 but in another array, 4th element `id` is 5, so your *"merge these arrays on the same id"* makes no sense as by merging 4th elements into one you also merge their children, and since `id` is used in both arrays, once value HAVE TO be gone as there cannot be two equal keys in array.

**EDIT**

you have to merge manually as PHP functions merge based on **keys** while you want to merge based on **content**:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $arrayA as $keyA => $valA ) {
  foreach( $arrayB as $keyB => $valB ) {
     if( $valA['id'] == $valB['id'] ) {
       $result[$keyA] = $valA + $valB;

       // or if you do not care output keys, just
       // $result[] = $valA + $valB;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have corrected some mistakes in outputs, sorry for that. What I want is to take e.g `$first[0]['id']` (equals `5`) find same `id` in the second array, here `$second[4]['id']` and merge them into new array like so: `array('id'=>5, 'name'=>'Education', 'title'=>'Edu')`. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :) And sorry for misleading title.

Comment: No early `break`ing when a match is found?

Answer (score 2):

To provide an alternative approach available in `PHP 5.5+`.

Since the ordering of the two arrays is not identical, first use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to index the arrays by the `id`.

This will allow you to use [array_replace_recusrive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) on the `id` indexed arrays.

`array_replace_recursive` will merge the values in the arrays matching the index association of both array sets.

Optionally use `array_values` to reindex the array, removing the `id` index association.

### Example https://3v4l.org/ndv2j

```
$first = array_column($first, null, 'id');
$second = array_column($second, null, 'id');
$result = array_values(array_replace_recursive($first, $second));
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Education
            [title] => Edu
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Computers
            [title] => Comp
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Science
            [title] => Sci
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Sports
            [title] => Sport
        )

)
```

Comment: This snippet makes 4 functional loops.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use foreach in foreach,that might be too slow when the array so big.

```
$idArray = array_column($secondArray,'title','id');
foreach($firstArray as $key => $val){
  $firstArray[$key]['title'] = (isset($idArray[$val['id']])) ? $idArray[$val['id']] : 'some title';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using the 3-parameter form of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index your `second` array by the `id` value and then looping over the `first` array, merging the contents of the matching `second` value (where it exists):

```
$second = array_column($second, null, 'id');
foreach ($first as &$subject) {
    $subject = array_merge($subject, $second[$subject['id']] ?? []);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Education
            [title] => Edu
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Computers
            [title] => Comp
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Science
            [title] => Sci
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Sports
            [title] => Sport
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9BsEc)

This has the advantage over Will B.'s answer of not re-indexing the `first` array. It's also slightly faster (my tests show ~10%) due to only having one call to `array_column` and none to `array_values`.

**Update**

This code can actually be sped up even more by using the [array union operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (`+`) (thanks @mickmackusa):

```
$second = array_column($second, null, 'id');
foreach ($first as &$subject) {
    $subject += $second[$subject['id']] ?? [];
}
```

The output of this code is the same as above, but it runs about 10% faster again.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Hbuc0)

Comment: This answer is probably as optimized for speed as it can be, but bear in mind that the call of `array_column()` will lose data IF there are duplicate `id` column values in the `$second` array.  (This is just a fringe consideration for readers, because the sample data in the question does not have duplicated  `id` column values in the `$second` array.)

Comment: Another fringe scenario would be if the `$first` array did not contain an `id` value that corresponds to the `$second` array, the data from the `$second` would be omitted from the result.  This may or may not be a desired behavior.  In the posted question all available `id` values are represented in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Sort both arrays by your 'id' field, then let php do the merge with array_replace_recursive.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return ((int) $a['id'] < (int) $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array1, 'cmp');
usort($array2, 'cmp');

$result = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: This untested snippet is clearly incorrect in its output.

Comment: Hey @mickmackusa, well spotted. This code works fine with `array_replace_recursive` but not with `array_merge`, obviously!

Comment: I still don't recommend this technique because `usort()` will require greater computation complexity versus other answers on this page.  I'm biased because I cooperated with Nick already, but -- I'd use Nick's answer.  This assumes that both arrays contain the same volume and data structure.  It also requires both arrays to share the same ids.  This answer is not reliable for general use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the items are in the same order then:

```
$items = array_map(function($itemFirstArray, $itemSecondArray) {
  return array_merge($itemFirstArray, $itemSecondArray);
}, $firstArray, $secondArray);
```

Comment: It probably makes sense to not yatta-yatta over the bit of code that ensures that the two arrays are sorted correctly.  To be clear, this technique requires that both arrays contain exactly and only the same id-related data.

Comment: This answer requires that both arrays are the same length and have exactly the same mapping column values.