# Merging two n-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two n-dimensional arrays which I would like to merge. I have already reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669554/merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-on-specific-key), however, it is only good for merging two dimensional arrays. I am trying to accomplish the same thing, except with two n-dimensional arrays.

So, for example:

Array 1:

```
Array (
    [''] => 'ID One'
    ['foo'] => Array (
        [''] => 'ID Two'
        ['bar'] => 'ID Three'
    )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array (
    ['foo'] => Array (
        ['bar'] => Array (
            ['baz'] => 'ID Four'
        )
    )
    ['bax'] => 'ID Five'
)
```

Desired Array Result:

```
Array (
    [''] => 'ID One'
    ['foo'] => Array (
        [''] => 'ID Two'
        ['bar'] => Array (
            [''] => 'ID Three'
            ['baz'] => 'ID Four'
        )
    )
    ['bax'] => 'ID Five'
)
```

Although this is a demonstration of what I am trying to achieve, when it is being used for some web apps, it is entirely possible that it will have 10, perhaps even 15 nested arrays. So, how can Array 1 and Array 2 be merged to form the Desired Array Result?

Comment: Can't you just use `array_merge_recursive`?

Comment: Ok, feeling stupid now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conveniently, [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) does exactly that!

[This demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fld0HE) covers the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge-recursive.php) or [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-replace-recursive.php).

If neither of those functions does what you want, it's still easy to do with a recursive function, e.g.:

```
function merge($a, $b) {
    foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value) {
            $a[$key] = $value;
        } else if (isset($a[$key])) {
            $a[$key] = merge($a[$key], $value);
        } else {
            $a[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

$merged = merge($a, $b);
```