# Combine 2 array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-000-000
            [name] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-789-014
            [name] => james
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-000-000
            [address] => Japan
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tin] => 123-456-789-014
            [address] => Spain
        )

)
```

I have 2 array above and I want to combine them so i used [array-merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). But I didnt get the result i want. What it gave me is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-000-000
            [name] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-789-014
            [name] => james
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tin] => 123-456-000-000
            [address] => Japan
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tin] => 123-456-789-014
            [address] => Spain
        )

)
```

What i wanted is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-000-000
            [name] => john
            [address] => Japan
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-789-014
            [name] => james
            [address] => Spain
        )

)
```

How to achieve this kind of array merge

Comment: Will you always have arrays of equal length?

Comment: @Terminus what do you mean by equal length?if you mean same number of array yes always.but there are more values i just shorten them. in first array there are last name etc. while second one it breaks down to country city district..i hope i answered it correctly

Comment: @Terminus because they are pair...in one array it is personal information of the person and the other is the address information

Comment: Just compare one by one. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669554/merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-on-specific-key
It might solve your problem but I am sure it isn't the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume both array have the same number of elements and in the same order, then one `foreach` loop can do the job

```
$arr1 = Array (
    0 => Array (
        "id" => "123-456-000-000",
        "name" => "john"
    ),
    1 => Array (
        "id" => "123-456-789-014",
        "name" => "james"
    )

);
$arr2 = Array (
    0 => Array (
        "tin" => "123-456-000-000",
        "address" => "Japan"
    ),
    1 => Array (
        "tin" => "123-456-789-014",
        "address" => "Spain"
    )
);

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $inner) {
    $arr1[$key]["address"] = $inner["address"];
}
```

output: `$arr1`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-000-000
            [name] => john
            [address] => Japan
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123-456-789-014
            [name] => james
            [address] => Spain
        )

)
```

Comment: It would have been much better if you made the fiddle for the same.. I've done that for you.. Check it: https://3v4l.org/msWNs

Comment: thanks, I usually just post it here and have never thought of posting on external site

Comment: @user3514160 @ Andrew Great help guys appreacited

Comment: @MLM Glad to hear that.. @ Andrew Most welcome. Try to include the fiddle next time as it will help the future visitors who stumble upon to this question finding for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your arrays are at the same size and that your IDs are ordered int he same way.

Then you can try:

```
$arrayReturn = array();
foreach( $array1 as $key1 => $result1 ){
    $mergeArray = [$result1['id'], $result1['name'], $array2[$key1]['name']];
    array_push($arrayReturn, $mergeArray);
}
```

Where $array1 and $array2 are both of my initial arrays. $arrayReturn is my result.
Is there no other ways for you to directly merge the arrays at their creation? It would be much more elegant and will avoid all that.