# Merging two multi-dimensional arrays using key and adding values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to merge two array's using key(product_id) and adding that values(usage).
**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Reschedule A Service 
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adding An Image
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Each Calendar Event
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 14
        )

)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adding An Image
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Schedule A Service
            [usage] => 3
            [product_id] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Each Calendar Event
            [usage] => 2
            [product_id] => 14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sales Performance Dashboard
            [usage] => 2
            [product_id] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Quote
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 32
        )

)
```

I need an out put like this merging and adding usage values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adding An Image
            [usage] => 2
            [product_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Schedule A Service
            [usage] => 3
            [product_id] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Each Calendar Event
            [usage] => 3
            [product_id] => 14
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sales Performance Dashboard
            [usage] => 2
            [product_id] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Quote
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 32
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Reschedule A Service 
            [usage] => 1
            [product_id] => 8
        )

)
```

This is my code for creating arrays

```
    foreach($query->rows as $product){

     $top_products[]=array(
        'name'=>$product['name'],
        'usage'=>$product['pusage'],
        'product_id'=>$product['product_id']
     );

    }
```

```
    foreach($query_2->rows as $product){        

         $top_point_products[]=array(
           'name'=>$product['name'],
           'usage'=>$product['p_usage'],
           'product_id'=>$product['product_id']
         );

    }
```

Comment: Please post your code too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two multidimensional arrays on specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669554/merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-on-specific-key)

Comment: @Daniyal thats a different one here i need to add usage values,There they are merging only title with name

Comment: @ASR I have added my code also

Answer (score 1):

```
$first =array(

    array(
        "name" => "Reschedule A Service",
        "usage" => 1,
        "product_id" => 8
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Adding An Image",
        "usage" => 1,
        "product_id" => 5
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Each Calendar Event",
        "usage" => 1,
        "product_id" => 14
    )
    );
$second =array(


    array(
        "name" => "Adding An Image",
        "usage" => 1,
        "product_id" => 5
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Schedule A Service",
        "usage" => 3,
        "product_id" => 11
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Each Calendar Event",
        "usage" => 2,
        "product_id" => 14
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Sales Performance Dashboard",
        "usage" => 2,
        "product_id" => 30
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Quote",
        "usage" => 1,
        "product_id" => 32
    )
);

$result = array_unique(array_merge($first,$second), SORT_REGULAR);
```

> Use array_unique & array_merge

Comment: Yes but when i use array_unique i cannot add usage value of two arrays

Comment: I want add two arrays while merging for example product_id=>5 in 1 st array need to add usage values with product_id=>5 in second array

Comment: do you want to overwrite second array's usage value ?

Comment: if yes then just replace the first and second array like this

Comment: $result = array_unique(array_merge($second,$first), SORT_REGULAR);

Comment: yes have in first array "Adding An Image" usage is =1 and second array "Adding An Image" usage is =1 so in my result "Adding An Image" usage value is need to be 2.

Comment: shan array unique wont because second array values are different from first array

Comment: you want to add "usage value" while merging the array ?

Comment: Yes while merging i want to add usage value

Comment: You can use array_walk_recursive() to get a general-case solution for your problem (the one when each inner array can possibly have unique keys).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_merge function`, like this:

```
$C = array_merge($A, $B);
print_r($C);
```

[Read manual Array merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

> **try this code**

```
<?php

$array1=array
(
    0 => array(
            'name' => "Reschedule A Service", 
            'usage' => 1,
            'product_id' => 8
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Adding An Image",
            'usage' => 1,
            'product_id' => 5
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Each Calendar Event",
            'usage' => 2,
            'product_id' => 14
        )

);

$array2=array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Adding An Image",
            'usage' => 1,
            'product_id' => 5
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Schedule A Service",
            'usage' => 3,
            'product_id' => 11
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Each Calendar Event",
            'usage' => 5,
            'product_id' => 14
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Sales Performance Dashboard",
            'usage' => 2,
            'product_id' => 30
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            'name' => "Quote",
            'usage' => 1,
            'product_id' => 32
        )

);

$product_id1=array_column($array1, 'product_id');  
$product_id2=array_column($array2, 'product_id');  

$new=array_intersect($product_id1,$product_id2);

foreach ($new as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($new[$key],$product_id2)){
        $array2[array_search($new[$key],$product_id2)]['usage']+=$array1[$key]['usage'];
      }
}
$new1=array_diff($product_id1,$product_id2);
foreach ($new1 as $key => $value) {
        $array2[]=$array1[$key];
 }

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    echo "[".$key."]=><br>";
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
        echo "[".$key1."]=>".$value1."<br>";

    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

**output**

> [0]=>
>         [name]=>Adding An Image
>         [usage]=>2
>         [product_id]=>5
>
> [1]=>
>         [name]=>Schedule A Service
>         [usage]=>3
>         [product_id]=>11
>
> [2]=>
>         [name]=>Each Calendar Event
>         [usage]=>7
>         [product_id]=>14
>
> [3]=>
>         [name]=>Sales Performance Dashboard
>         [usage]=>2
>         [product_id]=>30
>
> [4]=>
>         [name]=>Quote
>         [usage]=>1
>         [product_id]=>32
>
> [5]=>
>         [name]=>Reschedule A Service
>         [usage]=>1
>         [product_id]=>8

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge` and a simple `foreach` loop to check your condition and update the `usage`values.

See below

```
$result = array_merge($arrArray1, $arrArray2);

$result2 = array(); 

foreach($result as $key => $value){
        if(array_key_exists($value['product_id'], $result2)){
               $result2[$value['product_id']]['usage'] +=  $value['usage'];
        } else{
            $result2[$value['product_id']] = $value;
        }
}

print_r($result2);
```

If you want to reset your resultant array indexes use `array_merge` again like this

```
$result2 = array_merge($result2);
```

Hope this will help